# Microsoft Azure Subnet Blocking

Tags: azure, networking

I have a big environment in Azure which includes several networks for several customers. Every subnet within the Vnet is for a random customer. 
I want to block the default routs in the subnets that I will not have access from one subnet to another in the same Vnet.

in which way should I perform it? create UDR? block it with NSG?

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: If the customers mean VMs or any others?

Comment: Yes VM's. forgot to mention that.

Comment: So you can add rules to block the traffic in the NSG and associate the NSG to the NIC of the VMs.

Comment: @Elso if the reply is helpful, you can accept it to close your question or let me know if you need further help.

Comment: @Elso if the reply is helpful, you can mark it as an answer to close your question or let me know if you need further help.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to block the access from one subnet to another in the same Vnet. You can add higher priority rule (source VirtualNetwork and destination VirtualNetwork, action Deny) in your NSG attached to each of subnet.

[image].